# top-down community detection in a network

Tags: algorithm, social-networking, igraph, modularity

I'm trying to find a way to find network communities in a top-down way. Most of the algorithms available (e.g. in the igraph package) are working bottom up - that is they start by assuming all nodes are singleton communities, and then combine them to larger communities. I want to got the other way around, similar to how decision trees are built: start with the whole network, then find a split that improves some "measure of information", etc.

Does anyone know of such algorithm or such a measure? I can't find such in the literature, but maybe I am missing something.

Also, what bothers me with some measures of modularity is that if you think of the whole network as one module, then all edges are within module and no out-module edges exist, so this seems like a perfect partition into a modules. Is there a measure that overcome this limitation?

Comment: You could approximate sparsest cut.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the concept of modularity - it doesn't simply count the number of edges within modules modules but it also compares this with the expected number of such edges if one randomized the network while keeping the degree distribution. A community structure is then considered good (i.e. have a high modularity) if there are much more edges within communities than the expectation. If you put every node in the same module, the modularity will be zero because no matter how you randomize the network, the edges would still be within modules.

Comment: Thanks, @Tamas. I actually understands this well. I just didn't find the algorithm. However, as you already raised this issue, I will argue that in social network, comparing the number of edges to an expected number by randomization is not realistic. edges in social network data tend to not follow a completely random structure. rather the distribution is different, so you would expect more edges within the cluster merely because it is a social network. so the modularity is likelyl to underestimate the random baseline, and hence overestimate the "real" modularity score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Newman's algorithm](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1482622/pdf/zpq8577.pdf) meets your requirements.

It works by computing "network modularity" and then splitting the network into two groups. After that it recursively applies the same principle to the newly formed groups until no further increase in modularity is possible.

It should also be implemented in `igraph`. At least in the [r version](http://igraph.org/r/doc/leading.eigenvector.html).